# SQL Server ISNULL function evaluating empty string as Zero(0)

Tags: sql-server

Can anybody explain why the following query is evaluating the to 'null' even though the value assigned to the @Test = NULL and it is checked against 0 in CASE?

```
declare @Test varchar = NULL
    SELECT (CASE ISNULL(@Test, '')
            WHEN 0 THEN 'null'
            ELSE 'not null'
        END) as 'value'
```

this returns 'null'

AND

```
declare @Test varchar = NULL
    SELECT (CASE ISNULL(@Test, '')
            WHEN '' THEN 'null'
            ELSE 'not null'
        END) as 'value'
```

this also returns 'null'

so evaluating ISNULL(NULL,'') to '' or 0 does not make any difference?

Comment: You are implicitly casting @Test to an INT before comparing with 0 - the equivalent of  `WHEN CAST(@Test AS INT) = 0`.

Comment: To compare `''` against `0` the server has to cast it to int first, ie to 0.  What are you trying to do with that code? Why not use the appropriate `IS NULL`, ie `CASE WHEN @Test IS NULL then ... ELSE .. END`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the explaination
Actually I was going thru some older moules in a project and I found this code like in the 1st condition of the question. and I was like why is it not evaluating the condition as false while evaluating '' to 0

Comment: @RajanPatel I hope this is the smallest snake you'll find in the module. Unfortunately, such snakes have company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way to try it out as below

```
CASE WHEN  @Test IS NULL THEN 0  -- Type numeric
     ELSE '-'                 -- Type VARCHAR
     END AS outputvlaue
```

this will give you an error as you cannot have two return type out of a case expression, so try as below

```
CASE WHEN  @Test IS NULL THEN 0  -- Type numeric
     ELSE 123                 -- Type numeric
     END AS outputvlaue
```

above will work

---

output of query is correct `ISNULL(@Test, '')` means return '' value when there is null.

Both query works because case..when expression when you try like this

```
  SELECT (CASE ISNULL(@Test, '')
            WHEN 0 THEN 'null'
            ELSE 'not null'
        END) as 'value'
```

Isnull returns you true value , as expression you given in case expression  evaluated as true which is ISNULL(@Test, '') and its true ..

so you have to try like this

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULL,'') = '' 
     THEN 'a' 
     ELSE 'b' 
  END
```

will return you 'a'

Comment: output of 2nd query seems correct. but why it is not returning 'not null'  as ISNULL(NULL,'') will return '' and we are checking it against 0.

Comment: @RajanPatel your code asks for `''` to be converted to 0 before checking. Why aren't you using `IS NULL` ? Why the convertion to `''` and then to int?

Comment: @RajanPatel - because in first case it comparing with numeric vlaue thats why it get worked ..you can tried first case like this CASE ISNULL(@Test, 1)
            WHEN 0 THEN 'null'
            ELSE 'not null'